# Merge with JPA and subclass ID

Tags: jpa

I got two entities like this (second one have a relation with first one) :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FOA_ADRESSE_ICX")
public class FoaAdresseIcx implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID_ADRESSE", unique=true, nullable=false, precision=5)
    private long idAdresse;

    @Column(length=32)
    private String bat;

    @Column(name="COD_POSTAL", length=5)
    private String codPostal;

    // getters and setters ....
}

@Entity
@Table(name="FOA_INFOS_ICX")
public class FoaInfosIcx implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="COD_ICX", unique=true, nullable=false, length=8)
    private String codIcx;

    @Column(name="DATE_RAFFRAICHISEMENT")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateRaffraichisement;

    @Column(name="LIB_AGENCE", nullable=false, length=98)
    private String libAgence;

    //uni-directional many-to-one association to FoaAdresseIcx
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_ADRESSE", nullable=false)
    private FoaAdresseIcx foaAdresseIcx;

    // getters and setters....
}
```

I got a problem with the merge :

```
myEntityMgr.merge(myFoaInfosIcx);
```

Got this exception :

```
GRAVE: EJB Exception: : javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.groupama.middlgan.entities.FoaAdresseIcx with id 0
```

In `myFoaInfosIcx` id is 0 because I don't initialise it, because I want JPA to create new FoaAdresseIcx in database if doesn't exist.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using primitive types as DB ids has the downside you are currently experiencing. The default value is `0`, which is a perfectly valid value for a DB id.

The persistence provider assumes that the entity is not new, but detached and behaves accordingly.

A solution is to use wrapper classes (or other non-primitive classes like `UUID`) as ids - `Long` in you case. Unless explicitly instantiated, the id attributes will be `null` and the provider will correctly identify an entity as new.